# How do I add an image field to my node.tpl.php template using render($content['field_example'])?

Tags: 7, theming, bootstrap-theme

I am creating a Bootstrap sub-theme and want to customize my node.tpl.php template. I have an image field with a machine name of 'field_poster'. According to the default node template:

> $content: An array of node items. Use render($content) to print them all,
> or print a subset such as render($content['field_example']). Use
> hide($content['field_example']) to temporarily suppress the printing of a
> given element.

So, doesn't this mean I can add `print render($content['field_poster']);` to my node.tpl.php and it will output the image, right? Well, I've tried that and it does **nothing**!

How can I get my image field to render in my template?

### Update

My `field_poster` was set to display within a Field Group in *Display Settings*. This changes how things work in the template. See below for my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here was the problem. My `field_poster` was nested in a Field Group under display settings. Apparently, you need to include the parent field group if you want to render child fields outside the group.

So, if my container field group is named `group_fieldgroup1` I need to use the following to render my field:

`<?php print render($content['group_fieldgroup1']['field_poster']); ?>`

You can render the entire field group by using the following.

`<?php print render($content['group_fieldgroup1']); ?>`